# Reverse smil animation based on path

Tags: animation, svg, smil

I'm new to SVG and trying to reverse run the animation instead of starting it from the beginning. Is there a way to do it using SMIL or should I just switch to keyframes?

```
`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LayQRL`
```

Thanks for all help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `values` attribute instead of `to` like this:
The red path is what you have, the blue one is using 3 `values`

I hope this is what you are asking.

```css
svg {
 border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 849 681">
       
    <path fill="red" d="M44.2832799,204.535103 C157.481114,264.166986 230.550155,376.259161 263.490405,540.811627 C312.90078,787.640326 488.600718,1162.61771 1328.65457,1020.992959 C1888.69048,814.909789 1875.38066,525.653653 1288.72512,86.2245504 L44.2832799,204.535103 Z" id="path-2">
      <animate attributeName="d" dur="5000ms" repeatCount="indefinite" to="M44.2832799,.535103 C157.481114,64.166986 100.550155,550.259161 500.490405,700.811627 C812.90078,787.640326 488.600718,1162.61771 1328.65457,953.992959 C1888.69048,814.909789 1875.38066,525.653653 1288.72512,86.2245504 L44.2832799,204.535103 Z" rotate="auto" keyPoints="1;0">
      </animate>
    </path>
 
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 849 681" width="200">
         
    <path fill="skyblue" d="M44.2832799,204.535103 C157.481114,264.166986 230.550155,376.259161 263.490405,540.811627 C312.90078,787.640326 488.600718,1162.61771 1328.65457,1020.992959 C1888.69048,814.909789 1875.38066,525.653653 1288.72512,86.2245504 L44.2832799,204.535103 Z" >
      <animate attributeName="d" dur="5000ms" repeatCount="indefinite"
         values="M44.2832799,204.535103 C157.481114,264.166986 230.550155,376.259161 263.490405,540.811627 C312.90078,787.640326 488.600718,1162.61771 1328.65457,1020.992959 C1888.69048,814.909789 1875.38066,525.653653 1288.72512,86.2245504 L44.2832799,204.535103 Z;
                 
          M44.2832799,.535103 C157.481114,64.166986 100.550155,550.259161 500.490405,700.811627 C812.90078,787.640326 488.600718,1162.61771 1328.65457,953.992959 C1888.69048,814.909789 1875.38066,525.653653 1288.72512,86.2245504 L44.2832799,204.535103 Z;
                 
          M44.2832799,204.535103 C157.481114,264.166986 230.550155,376.259161 263.490405,540.811627 C312.90078,787.640326 488.600718,1162.61771 1328.65457,1020.992959 C1888.69048,814.909789 1875.38066,525.653653 1288.72512,86.2245504 L44.2832799,204.535103 Z "      
      />
  </path>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, thats basically what I've been looking for. Could you specify what the 3 values you assigned mean? Is the first one is the starting one, the second is what it goes to and the third where the animation goes back?

Comment: The 3 values are the value of the `d` attribute at the beginning , in the middle and at the end of the animation. The he first one and the last one are the same (the d attribute for the red path in your example) . The second value is the one you are using for the `to` attribute of the `<animate>` element.